# Sending Data Error with angular's $http.put

Tags: angularjs, http, put

Whenever i fire this put method :

```
return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/upvote', {
  headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
}).success(function(data){
  post.upvotes += 1;
});
```

I get the following error :

PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/56d89bfbb906ee1305fea2cf/upvote 401 (Unauthorized)

From what I understand, this is an angular issue with the way that its put method supports sending data to the server.

Can anyone who has dealt with this issue before help me out by.

-Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Try to send that message with https://www.getpostman.com/ same result?

Comment: don't see why it would be an angular issue. Is server set up for put? Is auth header correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the HTTP header before hand:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer '+ auth.getToken();
```

Then call your PUT request

Comment: That worked! 

Would give you an upvote but my rank is too low :(

When/if you have time can you please explain why my original method didn't work and yours does. 

Also what if some actions do not require authorization, but the common header is set up for all http requests coming to my server, is there any way to distinguish between those actions that do require auth and those that dont.

Im very new to working with authorization with angular so please excuse me if that question was stupid.

In the mean time im going to do some more reading on $http

Comment: I think you can still pass the header per request if you use the full version of $http({method:'PUT',headers: { .... }) rather than $http.put. Try that it might still work for you. Also this page is a good read of how $http works in general https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.